# Sequences (Mathematical Induction)

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction

Can any one help me with this.

We have 
$$
U_n=\frac{n^3}{n^4+1}+\frac{n^3}{n^4+2}...+\frac{n^3}{n^4+n}
$$
How to prove that, for all $n$:
$$
\frac{n^4}{n^4+n}\le U_n\le \frac{n^4}{n^4+1}
$$

and what the limit of the sequence ?

I've proved that for $U_0$ but I couldn't prove that for $n+1.$

Thanks too much

Comment: How is $U_0$ even defined by this expression?

Comment: "Thanks too much' is may be a little... too much

Answer (score 1):

Remark that $\frac{n^3}{n^4+1}$ is the largest term in the expression of $U_n$ so you can upperbound the value of $U_n$ by taking $n\cdot\frac{n^3}{n^4+1}$. Similarly for the lower-bound you can remark that $\frac{n^3}{n^4+n}$ is the smaller term in $U_n$.

Now for the limit... wait one sec ;-)

Using the bound just found you can write
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n^4}{n^4+n}\leq \lim_{n\to\infty} U_n\leq\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n^4}{n^4+1}
$$

Hence $\lim_{n\to\infty} U_n=1$.

But there is not induction here...

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{array}\\
U_n
&=\frac{n^3}{n^4+1}+\frac{n^3}{n^4+2}...+\frac{n^3}{n^4+n}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{n^3}{n^4+i}\\
&=\dfrac1{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{n^4}{n^4+i}\\
&=\dfrac1{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{1+i/n^4}\\
&<\dfrac1{n}\sum_{i=1}^n 1\\
&=1\\
\text{and}\\
U_n
&=\dfrac1{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{1+i/n^4}\\
&>\dfrac1{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{1+n/n^4}\\
&>\dfrac1{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{1+1/n^3}\\
&=\frac{1}{1+1/n^3}\\
&>1-\dfrac1{n^3}
\qquad\text{since }\dfrac1{1+x} > 1-x \text{ for } 0 < x < 1\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: Exact, but i'm afraid the OP needs an induction proof.

Comment: The way the $n$'s occur makes an induction proof appear quite difficult.

Comment: I agree with you.